# Windows App Resolution

Tags: c#, resolution, dpi

I have a windows app that runs correctly in my PC that is 96DPI but when I use it on a PC that has 120DPI the forms transform and all their components scramble.

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did any answers help you? It would be helpful for you to follow up and tell us if your problem was solved (mark the answer) or give the Stackoverflow community an update on your problem.  That way, we will know whether you are still seeking a solution.

Comment: Yes, actually I followed your answer and used panels, but I got deeply in that thing so I dindt return to Stackoverflow even to check for more answers.

But thank you, I really don't know how to close a question so I'll try answering it, I did it once and it worked.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to use dynamic layout in your forms.  You can use AutoSize, Docking/Anchoring, Padding, Margin, TableLayoutPanel, FlowLayoutPanel, etc, to structure your form so the actual positioning of your controls is done at run-time instead of compile-time.  That way, your form will retain its layout even when the DPI is different.  "Programming Microsoft Windows Forms" by Charles Petzold is a good book on Windows Forms.  Chapter 3 of that book is full of information about how to use dynamic layout.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean you have the source for the application (development question) you can check the DPI setting of the display the application is running on and re-format your interface as needed depending on the resolution.

If you mean that you have a compiled application from somewhere else and you don't have the source code for it you can set your resolution to 96 DPI.

Hope that helps.